# Android, EditText events, Prevent some parts of the text can be deleted / changed

Tags: android, events, android-edittext

I try to add an event handle to a EditText object (a text area the use can edit) in my Android App to control what the use can edit or not.
Say I have this text in my EditText:

```
   * Hello 
   * World
   * On You...
```

I will attach a controller that allows the user to only edit the `Hello`, `World` or `On You`, and if the user try to edit or remove the `*` and the first space after `*` the system will stop the edit.

On Java SE I can use [Document.remove(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#remove%28int,%20int%29) for getting event while an user try to remove or replace a part of the text and then stop the edit.

Is there a similar API for android EditText?

I have tried using [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) but from what I know this is not going to help  me,
I know method [`public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) give some notes about the which text user remove but this seem unreliable. 
And this give me not a way for this matter to stop the edit of use.

**EDIT:**
Can I use a Spanner for prevent edit to be do for a part of the text? As a readonly spanner?

Someone knows a good way to fix my problems?

Comment: You said **" but this seem unreliable"** -- Please explain why.

Comment: Yes not realy unreliable, but this give me the hole word and not the enter char, If I on the phone enter "Hello" this will first give me "H", "He", "Hel", "Hell" "Hello" this is for me not what I want. I'm try now to translaite this into what I will has, I has find out `InputFilter` for edit/denied edit on the fly, but has here same problemes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I has final find a working solustion, but has to be try more deeply to know if this exist some buggs or errors.

```
public abstract class TextListener implements InputFilter {

    public abstract CharSequence removeStr(CharSequence removeChars, int startPos);

    public abstract CharSequence insertStr(CharSequence newChars, int startPos);

    public abstract CharSequence updateStr(CharSequence oldChars, int startPos, CharSequence newChars);

    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        CharSequence returnStr = source;
        String curStr = dest.subSequence(dstart, dend).toString();
        String newStr = source.toString();
        int length = end - start;
        int dlength = dend - dstart;
        if (dlength > 0 && length == 0) {
            // Case: Remove chars, Simple
            returnStr = TextListener.this.removeStr(dest.subSequence(dstart, dend), dstart);
        } else if (length > 0 && dlength == 0) {
            // Case: Insert chars, Simple
            returnStr = TextListener.this.insertStr(source.subSequence(start, end), dstart);
        } else if (curStr.length() > newStr.length()) {
            // Case: Remove string or replace
            if (curStr.startsWith(newStr)) {
                // Case: Insert chars, by append
                returnStr = TextUtils.concat(curStr.subSequence(0, newStr.length()), TextListener.this.removeStr(curStr.subSequence(newStr.length(), curStr.length()), dstart + curStr.length()));
            } else {
                // Case Replace chars.
                returnStr = TextListener.this.updateStr(curStr, dstart, newStr);
            }
        } else if (curStr.length() < newStr.length()) {
            // Case: Append String or rrepace.
            if (newStr.startsWith(curStr)) {
                // Addend, Insert
                returnStr = TextUtils.concat(curStr, TextListener.this.insertStr(newStr.subSequence(curStr.length(), newStr.length()), dstart + curStr.length()));
            } else {
                returnStr = TextListener.this.updateStr(curStr, dstart, newStr);
            }
        } else {
            // No update os str...
        }

        // If the return value is same as the source values, return the source value.
        return TextUtils.equals(source, returnStr) ? source : returnStr;
    }
}
```

From this code I can easy prevent edit on select part of the text by lookup were in the text I try to edit.